# TLS Handshake Failure with M2Mqtt in C# dockerized MQTT Client

Tags: c#, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

Here's a summary of the issue to post on Stack Overflow:

#### Issue Summary:

I have a Dockerized MQTT broker server where I want to add TLS connections using certificates from a private CA (root-ca.cer has signed server.cer as a trust chain ). I have configured the server and client code with certificates, and the server configuration seems correct. However, I'm encountering an error during the TLS handshake when the client tries to connect to the MQTT broker.

#### Server Code (Publisher):

```cs
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_SERVER_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);
                var certificateCA = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_CA_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);

                MqttClient client = new MqttClient(BrokerAddress, 8883, true,
                                       certificateCA,
                                       certificate,
                                       MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback);

               
                client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                client.Publish(topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
```

#### Client Code (Subscriber):

```cs
  // Cargar el certificado PFX
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_CLIENT_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);
                var certificateCA = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_CA_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);

                // Crear cliente MQTT con soporte TLS
                MqttClient client = new MqttClient(BrokerAddress, 8883, true,
                                       certificateCA,
                                       certificate,
                                       MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback);

                Console.WriteLine($"INFO: BROKER ADDRESS: {BrokerAddress}");

                client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
 //...
                };


                client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                client.Subscribe(new string[] { topic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.YELLOW}{Colors.BOLD}[info]{Colors.RESET} Subscribed to topic {Colors.BOLD}[{topic}]{Colors.RESET}");
            }
            catch (MqttClientException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.RED}{Colors.BOLD}[MQTT Connection Exception]{Colors.RESET} {ex}");
                // Manejo específico para errores de conexión MQTT
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.RED}{Colors.BOLD}[Socket Exception]{Colors.RESET} {ex}");
                // Manejo específico para errores de Socket
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.RED}{Colors.BOLD}[General Exception]{Colors.RESET} {ex}");
                // Manejo para cualquier otro tipo de error no capturado específicamente
            }
        }
```

RemoteCertificateValidationCallback returns always true. It works in local mode, not in dockerized mode.

#### Mosquitto Configuration (mosquitto.conf):

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log

listener 8883 0.0.0.0


# TLS
certfile /mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/certs/server.key


## Authentication ##
# By default, Mosquitto >=2.0 allows only authenticated connections. Change to true to enable anonymous connections.
require_certificate true
allow_anonymous true
log_type all
connection_messages true

# password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt
```

#### Server's Docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6
    container_name: mosquitto
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Madrid
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - ./mosquitto/certs:/mosquitto/certs
    ports:
      - "8883:8883"
    networks:
      - mls_network
    restart: unless-stopped

  mls_server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mls_server
    environment:
      - BROKER_IP_ADDRESS=mosquitto
    ports:
      - "10003:10003"
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
    networks:
      - mls_network
    volumes:
      - ./mls-server/keys:/mls-server/mls-server/keys
      - ./mls-server/data:/mls-server/mls-server/data
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  mls_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

#### Client's Docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mls_client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mls_client
    environment:
      BROKER_IP_ADDRESS: ${BROKER_IP_ADDRESS}
      SERVER_IP: ${SERVER_IP}
      N: ${N}
      ALGORITHM: ${ALGORITHM}
      TZ: Europe/Madrid
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "10003"
      - "8883"
    networks:
      - mls_network
    volumes:
      - ./mls-client/keys:/mls-client/keys
      - ./mls-client/data:/mls-client/data
      - ./mls-client/scripts:/mls-client/scripts
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  mls_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

#### Mosquitto log:

I have tried to see if there are uploaded certs as follows:

```
sudo docker exec -it 4a91e96b0825 ls /mosquitto/certs
server.crt  server.key
```

As you can see, they are in the correct place, but mosquitto cannot use them.

```
1703761378: mosquitto version 1.6.15 starting
1703761378: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1703761378: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1703761378: mosquitto version 1.6.15 running
1703761558: mosquitto version 1.6.15 terminating
1703761558: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data/mosquitto.db.
1703761821: mosquitto version 1.6.15 starting
1703761821: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1703761821: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1703761821: mosquitto version 1.6.15 running
1703761959: New connection from 172.22.0.4 on port 8883.
1703761959: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
1703761959: New connection from 172.22.0.4 on port 8883.
1703761959: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

#### Error Message:

```
[Exception] Exception in MQTT: uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker
...
mls_client    | [General Exception] uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker
mls_client    |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused 172.22.0.2:10003
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttNetworkChannel.Connect()
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
mls_client    |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId)
mls_client    |    at Idbotic.MlsClient.Utilities.Mqtt.SubscribeToMqttTopic(String topic) in /mls-client/src/Mqtt.cs:line 60
mls_client    | [General Exception] uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker
mls_client    |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused 172.22.0.2:10003
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttNetworkChannel.Connect()
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
mls_client    |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId)
mls_client    |    at Idbotic.MlsClient.Utilities.Mqtt.SubscribeToMqttTopic(String topic) in /mls-client/src/Mqtt.cs:line 60
mls_client exited with code 0
...
```

The server certificates (`server.cer`, `server.pem`, `root-ca.cer`) have been successfully copied to the Mosquitto container's path, and their existence has been confirmed.

#### Issue Details:

I'm encountering an SSL handshake failure (`error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure`) when trying to establish a TLS connection between the MQTT client and the broker. I have checked the certificates' presence and configuration, but the TLS handshake still fails. How can I resolve this SSL handshake issue and establish a secure connection between the MQTT client and the broker?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

Comment: Edit the question to include the mosquitto logs and details of how you have started the container (e.g. which ports are exposed). Also I suggest you re-arrange your `mosquitto.conf` file, move the listener line to above the `ca_file` as the persistence settings are not related to the listener and order matters for listeners/tls (and it's easier to read)

Comment: `new MqttClient(BrokerAddress, 8883, **false**,` why are you passing `false` in the `secure` parameter? (this differs from your "server" code).

Comment: I changed it to **true** as it must follow the secure connection, I was only trying different approaches. I am going to attach the Dockerfile and docker-compose. @hardillb can you explain it better?

Comment: Break this up into smaller problems. Fix the errors about not being able to read files in the mosquitto logs, then use an existing MQTT client to test that you can correctly connect and publish/subscribe to the broker, then introduce one of you server/client applications and test with the 3rd party client as the other side, then try all 3. As it is there are too many moving parts here.

Comment: Does the ca_file have to be from a real ca like lets encrypt? or could it be a root-ca.cer that I created to generate the trust chain of certificates as a private CA? @hardillb

Comment: Read the mosquitto docs, the `cafile` is ONLY used to validate client certificates, if you are not using client certs (which you do not appear to be) you do not need it all.

Comment: I am using a private CA with chain of trust, my root-ca.cer has signed the client and server certificates, so I was thinking that I must use it in the configuration. How can I configure the client and server without using that root-ca.cer? @hardillb

Comment: Clients still need the ca cert, but the broker does not

Comment: Hi, @hardillb I figure out that in local mode does work, but when dockerizing the server and client, mosquitto refuses the connection. I have also seen if the certificates are correctly uploaded to the container, and they are succesfully uplodaded, mqtt refuses the connection tho. Any suggestion?

Comment: Start a new question with just the up to date config files and logs (include the first lines of the mosquitto logs).

Comment: @hardillb  new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726584/tls-not-working-for-dockerized-mqtt-broker