# TLS not working for Dockerized MQTT broker

Tags: c#, mqtt, x509certificate, mosquitto

#### Issue Summary:

I have a Dockerized MQTT broker server where I want to add TLS connections using certificates from a private CA (root-ca.cer has signed server.cer as a trust chain ). I have configured the server and client code with certificates, and the server configuration seems correct.

However, I'm encountering an error during the TLS handshake when the client tries to connect to the MQTT broker. It is important to note that the broker accepts connections when running the server C# program and client C# program locally, the problem comes when Dockerizing it.

#### Server Code (Publisher):

```cs
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_SERVER_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);
                var certificateCA = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_CA_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);

                MqttClient client = new MqttClient(BrokerAddress, 8883, true,
                                       certificateCA,
                                       certificate,
                                       MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback);

               
                client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                client.Publish(topic, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
```

#### Client Code (Subscriber):

```cs
  // Cargar el certificado PFX
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_CLIENT_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);
                var certificateCA = new X509Certificate2(Constants.PATH_CA_CERT, Constants.CERT_PASSWORD);

                // Crear cliente MQTT con soporte TLS
                MqttClient client = new MqttClient(BrokerAddress, 8883, true,
                                       certificateCA,
                                       certificate,
                                       MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback);

                Console.WriteLine($"INFO: BROKER ADDRESS: {BrokerAddress}");

                client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
 //...
                };


                client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                client.Subscribe(new string[] { topic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.YELLOW}{Colors.BOLD}[info]{Colors.RESET} Subscribed to topic {Colors.BOLD}[{topic}]{Colors.RESET}");
            }
            catch (MqttClientException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.RED}{Colors.BOLD}[MQTT Connection Exception]{Colors.RESET} {ex}");
                // Manejo específico para errores de conexión MQTT
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.RED}{Colors.BOLD}[Socket Exception]{Colors.RESET} {ex}");
                // Manejo específico para errores de Socket
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Colors.RED}{Colors.BOLD}[General Exception]{Colors.RESET} {ex}");
                // Manejo para cualquier otro tipo de error no capturado específicamente
            }
        }
```

RemoteCertificateValidationCallback returns always true. It works in local mode, not in dockerized mode.

#### Mosquitto Configuration (mosquitto.conf):

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log



# TLS
certfile /mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/certs/server.key

listener 8883 0.0.0.0

## Authentication ##
# By default, Mosquitto >=2.0 allows only authenticated connections. Change to true to enable anonymous connections.
require_certificate true
allow_anonymous true
log_type all
connection_messages true

# password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt
```

#### Server's Docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6
    container_name: mosquitto
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Madrid
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - ./mosquitto/certs:/mosquitto/certs
    ports:
      - "8883:8883"
    networks:
      - mls_network
    restart: unless-stopped

  mls_server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mls_server
    environment:
      - BROKER_IP_ADDRESS=mosquitto
    ports:
      - "10003:10003"
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
    networks:
      - mls_network
    volumes:
      - ./mls-server/keys:/mls-server/mls-server/keys
      - ./mls-server/data:/mls-server/mls-server/data
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  mls_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

#### Client's Docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mls_client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mls_client
    environment:
      BROKER_IP_ADDRESS: ${BROKER_IP_ADDRESS}
      SERVER_IP: ${SERVER_IP}
      N: ${N}
      ALGORITHM: ${ALGORITHM}
      TZ: Europe/Madrid
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "10003"
      - "8883"
    networks:
      - mls_network
    volumes:
      - ./mls-client/keys:/mls-client/keys
      - ./mls-client/data:/mls-client/data
      - ./mls-client/scripts:/mls-client/scripts
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  mls_network:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

#### Mosquitto log:

I have tried to see if there are uploaded certs as follows:

```
sudo docker exec -it 4a91e96b0825 ls /mosquitto/certs
server.crt  server.key
```

As you can see, they are in the correct place, but Mosquitto cannot use them.

```
1703761378: mosquitto version 1.6.15 starting
1703761378: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1703761378: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1703761378: mosquitto version 1.6.15 running
1703761558: mosquitto version 1.6.15 terminating
1703761558: Saving in-memory database to /mosquitto/data/mosquitto.db.
1703761821: mosquitto version 1.6.15 starting
1703761821: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1703761821: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1703761821: mosquitto version 1.6.15 running
1703761959: New connection from 172.22.0.4 on port 8883.
1703761959: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
1703761959: New connection from 172.22.0.4 on port 8883.
1703761959: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

#### Error Message:

```
[Exception] Exception in MQTT: uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker
...
mls_client    | [General Exception] uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException: Exception connecting to the broker
mls_client    |  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
mls_client    |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
mls_client    |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Security.SyncReadWriteAdapter.ReadAsync(Stream stream, Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
mls_client    |    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
mls_client    |    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttNetworkChannel.Connect()
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
mls_client    |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod)
mls_client    |    at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId)
mls_client    |    at Idbotic.MlsClient.Utilities.Mqtt.SubscribeToMqttTopic(String topic) in /mls-client/src/Mqtt.cs:line 60

...
```

#### Wireshark stacktrace

```
o.
Time
Source
Destination
Protocol Length Info
6 0.028958980
172.22.0.4
172.22.0.3
TLSv1.2 240
Client Hello
Frame 6: 240 bytes on wire (1920 bits), 240 bytes captured (1920 bits) on interface br-ea462bdbcf2f, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:16:00:04 (02:42:ac:16:00:04), Dst: 02:42:ac:16:00:03 (02:42:ac:16:00:03)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.22.0.4, Dst: 172.22.0.3
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 35224, Dst Port: 10003, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 174
Source Port: 35224
Destination Port: 10003
[Stream index: 0]
[Conversation completeness: Complete, WITH_DATA (31)]
[TCP Segment Len: 174]
Sequence Number: 1
(relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 1462765100
[Next Sequence Number: 175
(relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 1
(relative ack number)
Acknowledgment number (raw): 2639933260
1000 .... = Header Length: 32 bytes (8)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window: 502
[Calculated window size: 64256]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x5908 [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
[Timestamps]
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
TCP payload (174 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
No.
Time
Source
Destination
Protocol Length Info
8 0.029708309
172.22.0.3
172.22.0.4
TLSv1.2 631
Server Hello,
Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
Frame 8: 631 bytes on wire (5048 bits), 631 bytes captured (5048 bits) on interface br-ea462bdbcf2f, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:16:00:03 (02:42:ac:16:00:03), Dst: 02:42:ac:16:00:04 (02:42:ac:16:00:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.22.0.3, Dst: 172.22.0.4
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 10003, Dst Port: 35224, Seq: 1, Ack: 175, Len: 565
Source Port: 10003
Destination Port: 35224
[Stream index: 0]
[Conversation completeness: Complete, WITH_DATA (31)]
[TCP Segment Len: 565]
Sequence Number: 1
(relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 2639933260
[Next Sequence Number: 566
(relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 175
(relative ack number)
Acknowledgment number (raw): 1462765274
1000 .... = Header Length: 32 bytes (8)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window: 508
[Calculated window size: 65024]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x5a8f [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
[Timestamps]
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
TCP payload (565 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
No.
Time
Source
Destination
Protocol Length Info
10 0.031269495
172.22.0.4
172.22.0.3
TLSv1.2 159
Client Key Exchange,
Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
Frame 10: 159 bytes on wire (1272 bits), 159 bytes captured (1272 bits) on interface br-ea462bdbcf2f, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:16:00:04 (02:42:ac:16:00:04), Dst: 02:42:ac:16:00:03 (02:42:ac:16:00:03)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.22.0.4, Dst: 172.22.0.3
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 35224, Dst Port: 10003, Seq: 175, Ack: 566, Len: 93
Source Port: 35224
Destination Port: 10003
[Stream index: 0]
[Conversation completeness: Complete, WITH_DATA (31)]
[TCP Segment Len: 93]
Sequence Number: 175
(relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 1462765274
[Next Sequence Number: 268
(relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 566
(relative ack number)
Acknowledgment number (raw): 2639933825/home/raul22520/Desktop/wireshark capture.pcapng 29 total packets, 6 shown
1000 .... = Header Length: 32 bytes (8)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window: 501
[Calculated window size: 64128]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x58b7 [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
[Timestamps]
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
TCP payload (93 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
No.
Time
Source
Destination
Protocol Length Info
11 0.031453420
172.22.0.3
172.22.0.4
TLSv1.2 117
Change Cipher Spec,
Encrypted Handshake Message
Frame 11: 117 bytes on wire (936 bits), 117 bytes captured (936 bits) on interface br-ea462bdbcf2f, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:16:00:03 (02:42:ac:16:00:03), Dst: 02:42:ac:16:00:04 (02:42:ac:16:00:04)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.22.0.3, Dst: 172.22.0.4
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 10003, Dst Port: 35224, Seq: 566, Ack: 268, Len: 51
Source Port: 10003
Destination Port: 35224
[Stream index: 0]
[Conversation completeness: Complete, WITH_DATA (31)]
[TCP Segment Len: 51]
Sequence Number: 566
(relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 2639933825
[Next Sequence Number: 617
(relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 268
(relative ack number)
Acknowledgment number (raw): 1462765367
1000 .... = Header Length: 32 bytes (8)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window: 508
[Calculated window size: 65024]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x588d [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
[Timestamps]
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
TCP payload (51 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
No.
Time
Source
Destination
Protocol Length Info
18 0.192256377
172.22.0.4
172.22.0.2
TLSv1
239
Client Hello
Frame 18: 239 bytes on wire (1912 bits), 239 bytes captured (1912 bits) on interface br-ea462bdbcf2f, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:16:00:04 (02:42:ac:16:00:04), Dst: 02:42:ac:16:00:02 (02:42:ac:16:00:02)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.22.0.4, Dst: 172.22.0.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 44512, Dst Port: 8883, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 173
Source Port: 44512
Destination Port: 8883
[Stream index: 1]
[Conversation completeness: Complete, WITH_DATA (47)]
[TCP Segment Len: 173]
Sequence Number: 1
(relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 1621308112
[Next Sequence Number: 174
(relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 1
(relative ack number)
Acknowledgment number (raw): 2769559624
1000 .... = Header Length: 32 bytes (8)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window: 502
[Calculated window size: 64256]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x5906 [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
[Timestamps]
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
TCP payload (173 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
No.
Time
Source
Destination
Protocol Length Info
24 0.214752917
172.22.0.4
172.22.0.2
TLSv1
239
Client Hello
Frame 24: 239 bytes on wire (1912 bits), 239 bytes captured (1912 bits) on interface br-ea462bdbcf2f, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 02:42:ac:16:00:04 (02:42:ac:16:00:04), Dst: 02:42:ac:16:00:02 (02:42:ac:16:00:02)/home/raul22520/Desktop/wireshark capture.pcapng 29 total packets, 6 shown
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.22.0.4, Dst: 172.22.0.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 44526, Dst Port: 8883, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 173
Source Port: 44526
Destination Port: 8883
[Stream index: 2]
[Conversation completeness: Complete, WITH_DATA (47)]
[TCP Segment Len: 173]
Sequence Number: 1
(relative sequence number)
Sequence Number (raw): 1525436432
[Next Sequence Number: 174
(relative sequence number)]
Acknowledgment Number: 1
(relative ack number)
Acknowledgment number (raw): 3435049632
1000 .... = Header Length: 32 bytes (8)
Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
Window: 502
[Calculated window size: 64256]
[Window size scaling factor: 128]
Checksum: 0x5906 [unverified]
[Checksum Status: Unverified]
Urgent Pointer: 0
Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
[Timestamps]
[SEQ/ACK analysis]
TCP payload (173 bytes)
Transport Layer Security
```

The server certificates (`server.crt`, `server.key`) have been successfully copied to the Mosquitto container's path, and their existence has been confirmed.

Comment: How do you know it's TLS? Can you get a Wireshark trace of the Server Hello and Client Hello?

Comment: @Charlieface I am trying to add TLS security bewtween my mqtt broker and client connections.

Comment: TLS the server sends a Certificate block with a list of certificate names that can be used.  The client can choose any of the certificate names in the list. The certificate has to be loaded in client and server before the HTTP request is sent. You can have client only choose one certificate. To check if this is a client or server issue you can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the TLS Certificate block to make sure server is sending the name of the certificate.  The names are not encrypted.  Also you can see the version of TLS being used to make sure the TLS version is correct.

Comment: I have edited the question with wireshark's stacktraces. I cannot see what is wrong by following the TLS handshake steps.

Comment: I am seeing that TLS version when trying to connect to the broker is TLSv1, perhaps it is that mqtt version 1.6 in docker is too outdated?

Comment: SOLUTION: UPDATE THE MOSQUITTO VERSION TO eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.18 IN DOCKER-COMPOSE

Comment: No it looks like TLSv1.2 is being used all the way. But there are pieces missing from your trace: we need to see the ciphers offered by both sides to see if there is a mismatch. We also want to see the certificates offered by both sides, in particular what SAN/DNS names are on them, and what hashin algorithm do they use.

Comment: As with your previous question the order of things in `mosquitto.conf` is important. The logs shown do not match the config shown; with this config mosquitto would listen on 1883 (default port but with tls enabled as per config) and 8883; the listener on port 8883 will not be using tls. If you are still having issues your need to simplify your question (use `mosquitto_sub` or `mqttx` first to get broker config right; be aware that `mosquitto_sub` defaults to tls on port 8883).

Comment: The `listener` line must come before the `certfile` & `keyfile` lines